# Error: use* functions may only be called during the `setup()` or other lifecycle hooks

Tags: vuejs3, urql, vue3-sfc-loader

I have this simple code inside `<script lang='ts' setup>`:

```js
let isServiceAlive = true;
let articles: IArticle[] = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => 
{
    await loadServiceStatus()

    if (isServiceAlive == false)
        return

    await loadArticles()
})

async function loadServiceStatus()
{
    const { data } = await useQuery(
    { 
        query: GetIsServiceAlive 
    })

    isServiceAlive = data.value.alive
}

async function loadArticles()
{
    const { data } = await useQuery(
    {
        query: GetArticlesQuery
    })

    articles.value = data.value.articles
}
```

I see nothing inherently wrong in it, but it pops this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: use* functions may only be called during the `setup()` or other lifecycle hooks.
    at useClient (useClient.ts?f3e5:28:1)
    at callUseQuery (useQuery.ts?cc4d:72:1)
    at useQuery (useQuery.ts?cc4d:64:1)
    at loadPosts (Index.vue?a170:39:1)
    at eval (Index.vue?a170:24:1)
```

It disappears as soon as I remove at least one of the calls `loadArticles` or `loadServiceStatus` - which is counterproductive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's not the default approach you should take with urql - but it's the only approach you want, if you don't want to wrap around reactive objects to access a single property that's returned from the query.

```js
<script lang='ts' setup>
import { IArticle } from '@/services'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { GetIsServiceAliveQuery } from './queries/GetIsServiceAliveQuery'
import { GetArticlesQuery } from './queries/GetArticlesQuery'
import { useQuery } from '@urql/vue'
import Article from './Article.vue'

let articles = ref(null)
let serviceAvailable = ref(false);

useQuery(
{
    query: GetIsServiceAliveQuery
})
.then(result => serviceAvailable.value = result.data.value.alive)

useQuery(
{
    query: GetArticlesQuery
})
.then(result => articles.value = result.data.value.articles)
</script>
```